# Texture Mapping without OpenGL

Tags: c++, visual-c++, textures, texture-mapping, interpolation

So I'm supposed to Texture Map a specific model I've loaded into a scene (with a Framebuffer and a Planar Pinhole Camera), however I'm not allowed to use OpenGL and I have no idea how to do it otherwise (we do use glDrawPixels for other functionality, but that's the only function we can use).

Is anyone here able enough to give me a run-through on how to texture map without OpenGL functionality?

I'm supposed to use these slides: https://www.cs.purdue.edu/cgvlab/courses/334/Fall_2014/Lectures/TMapping.pdf

But they make very little sense to me.

What I've gathered so far is the following:

You iterate over a model, and assign each triangle "texture coordinates" (which I'm not sure what those are), and then use "model space interpolation" (again, I don't understand what that is) to apply the texture with the right perspective.

I currently have my program doing the following:

[image: Teapot]

TL;DR:
1. What is model space interpolation/how do I do it?
2. What explicitly are texture coordinates?
3. How, on a high level (in layman's terms) do I texture map a model without using OpenGL.

Comment: Essentially you have to recreating what OpenGL does internally. Texture coordinates is something you have to somehow come up with (either specify them explicitly with the model or generate them based on e.g. the model's geometry). OpenGL requires to be supplied with texture coordinates either. The rest is actually quite basic stuff. I suggest you read the OpenGL-1.4 specification on texture application, namely how the fixed function pipeline does it. While the slides don't explain each and every step, but they carry all the information you need, given one knows how e.g. interpolation works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, let's start by making sure we're both on the same page about how the color interpolation works.  Lines 125 through 143 set up three vectors `redABC`, `greenABC` and `blueABC` that are used to interpolate the colors across the triangle.  They work one color component at a time, and each of the three vectors helps interpolate one color component.

By convention, s,t coordinates are in source texture space.  As provided in the mesh data, they specify the position within the texture of that particular vertex of the triangle.  The crucial thing to understand is that *s,t coordinates need to be interpolated across the triangle just like colors*.

So, what you want to do is set up two more `ABC` vectors: `sABC` and `tABC`, exactly duplicating the logic used to set up `redABC`, but instead of using the color components of each vertex, you just use the s,t coordinates of each vertex.  Then for each pixel, instead of computing `ssiRed` etc. as `unsigned int` values, you compute `ssis` and `ssit` as floats, they should be in the range `0.0f` through `1.0f` assuming your source s,t values are well behaved.

Now that you have an interpolated s,t coordinate, multiply `ssis` by the texel width of the texture, and `ssit` by the texel height, and use those coordinates to fetch the texel.  Then just put that on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not using OpenGL I assume you wrote your own software renderer to render that teapot?

A texture is simply an image. A texture coordinate is a 2D position in the texture. So (0,0) is bottom-left and (1,1) is top-right. For every vertex of your 3D model you should store a 2D position (u,v) in the texture. That means that at that vertex, you should use the colour the texture has at that point.

To know the UV texture coordinate of a pixel in between vertices you need to interpolate the texture coordinates of the vertices around it. Then you can use that UV to look up the colour in the texture.

Comment: I still don't quite understand the step-by-step. 
Should I load the texture into a FrameBuffer first? If so, then what?

The way I was currently thinking about it was to load a texture into a FrameBuffer and then go through it pixel by pixel and...do something?

I'm not 100% sure how to "store a 2D position in the texture" as you said.

Interpolation is also a little foreign to me. We've hardly be introduced to it, and I've had some difficulty finding solid examples of it in code.

Anything that can help take the abstract->actual implementation would be helpful!

Comment: You don't need to load the texture into the framebuffer or anything like that. The texture is just a piece of memory with the image in it.

Texture coordinates are 2D positions. If a vertex has texture coordinate (0.5, 0.5) then it needs to use the colour at the exact middle of the texture. If the vertex has texture coordinate (0.5, 0) then it needs to use the colour at the bottom of the texture, in the middle. Texture coordinates are just XY that define where to look in the image/texture.

Comment: Can you explain in a little more detail exactly what to do?

Do I go triangle - by triangle and do something? I know how to get all the triangles, but I'm not understanding exactly what you said above.

Comment: How do you render anything at all?

Comment: I have the following code in a TMesh class:

http://pastebin.com/DJZfdEZd

The RenderFilled() is then called on a TMesh. I could copy the whole class but I figured you wouldn't want all that.

Comment: In line 194 you calculate the colour of the pixel. The idea of texturing is that you replace that with code that looks up the colour in the texture.

Comment: So how do you look up the color in the texture? Model space interpolation?

Comment: So a texture is simply an image. Let's say we have a texture of 512x512 pixels. What we need to know when rendering a pixel to the screen is which pixel from the texture to use for the colour. Each vertex has a position in the world, three floats: X, Y and Z. Each vertex also has a position in the texture: U and V (two more floats per vertex). If you are rendering a pixel that is exactly at a vertex, you use exactly the UV at that vertex. So if the UV of that vertex is (0.5, 0.2) then you use the pixel from the texture with coordinates (0.5*512,0.2*512) = (256,102).

Comment: For pixels in between vertices you interpolate the positions of those vertices. In other words: you take a weighted average. Let's say you are closer to one vertex than to the other, maybe 20% along the way. Then the UVs for that pixel are 0.2 * vertex1.UV + 0.8 * vertex2.UV. This is called interpolating. In practice it is more complex, because you need to interpolate between all three vertices of the triangle. You can find tons of examples of how to do this on the internet.